# How to call to a function every time i click on a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javaScript. i want to call the start function every time i call the button. But it only work first time, after that every time i click on the button it do nothing. Please help me.
Below is my html and js.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Are you ready?</h1>
    <button id="start">start</button>
    <h1 id="canvas"></h1>
</div>
```

and js

```
var counter = 0;
var i = 0;
var words = ['jzg', 'oqs', 'lmb', 'ert', 'pkf', 'lhx', 'dyw'];
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var btn = document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click',start);

function start() {
function nextWord() {
    if (counter < words.length) {
        canvas.innerHTML = words[counter];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    counter++;
}

var show = setInterval(nextWord, 1000);
if (counter > words.length) {
    clearInterval(show);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you dont reset `counter` variable to `0` when clicking on `start` button. Also you need to check `clearInterval` inside of `nextWord` function.

```js
var counter = 0;
var i = 0;
var words = ['jzg', 'oqs', 'lmb', 'ert', 'pkf', 'lhx', 'dyw'];
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var btn = document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click',start);

function start() {

   counter = 0;
   var show;
   clearInterval(show)

   function nextWord() {
       
       console.log('here?');
       
       if (counter >= words.length) {
   
            clearInterval(show);
            canvas.innerHTML = '';
            
         }
   
       if (counter < words.length) {
        canvas.innerHTML = words[counter];
       } 
       counter++;
       
         
   }

  show = setInterval(nextWord, 1000);
  
  
  

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Are you ready?</h1>
    <button id="start">start</button>
    <h1 id="canvas"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped. can you tell me how can i also hide the last word once all the word showed? Because it seems the last word still appears, i also want to show it for 2sec like others word.

Comment: I updated my answer. To hide last word add `canvas.innerHTML = '';` when you clearing interval.

Comment: Yahh, that will do fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below code:
1. You were not able to do `clearInterval`. It was misplaced.
2. `You were not re-setting counter variable.`

I have commented the piece of code that was problematic/not working and inserted new code with comments as to why your old code was not working.
Hope it helps!

```js
var counter = 0;
    var i = 0;
    var words = ['jzg', 'oqs', 'lmb', 'ert', 'pkf', 'lhx', 'dyw'];
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var btn = document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click',start);

    function start() {
        function nextWord() {
            if (counter < words.length) {
                canvas.innerHTML = words[counter];
                counter++;
            } else {
                //return false;//<---Once you reach counter == words.length, 
                               //you are one past last index of `words` 
                               //array
                               
                clearInterval(show);//This is the time you should clear 
                                    //interval, so that clicking on button 
                                    //could set a new interval
                counter = 0;        //Set this to 0 since you want to begin 
                                    //again from the 0 index of words array
            }
            
        }

        var show = setInterval(nextWord, 1000);
        /*You were never reaching this code below since maximum value of counter was equal to `words.length`, which in this case was 7 and counter was never more than 7. That's why this part is moved to else part above */
        //if (counter > words.length) {
        //    clearInterval(show);
        //}
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <h1>Are you ready?</h1>
        <button id="start">start</button>
        <h1 id="canvas"></h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Roni Good to know that! However, I would recommend go through the comments I provided(if not done already). This would help you further!

Comment: I did and that helps to understand where the problem was.